# How to read data from textbox in ASP C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

there is an error in reading data from a text box here is the XML code:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 513px; position: absolute;
        top: 340px" Text="Search" Width="188px"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="MyTB" runat="server" Style="z-index: 101; left: 365px; position: absolute;
        top: 302px" Width="493px"/>
```

and here is the code where i call the textbox "MyTB" to read the data from it:

```
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = MyTB.Text;

        string[] textArr = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', ',' });
    }
```

The XML code :

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 513px; position: absolute;
        top: 340px" Text="Search" Width="188px"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="MyTB" runat="server" Style="z-index: 101; left: 365px; position: absolute;
        top: 302px" Width="493px"/>


</div>
```

Comment: And what, exactly, is the error you are receiving?  Because what you've shown so far should work.

Comment: What is the error? Your code to read the textbox text property is correct.

Comment: Error :The name 'MyTB' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. what the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Where are the `Button` and `TextBox` in the context of the entire page?  Are they embedded inside another control, such as a `DetailsView`, etc?

Comment: Here is the full XML code:
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 513px; position: absolute;
            top: 340px" Text="Search" Width="188px"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="MyTB" runat="server" Style="z-index: 101; left: 365px; position: absolute;
            top: 302px" Width="493px"/>
        
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: What is the relationship between the code you posted `btnSearch_Click` and the markup code?  Is it in the code-behind, or inside a script tag?  Can you show the `<@Page ...>` directive for the markup page?

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

Comment: Are you using a website, or web application project?  If the latter, do you see a designer file, e.g., `Default.aspx.designer.cs`?  Does it contain references to the textbox `MyTB` and button `btnSearch`?  Have you tried closing and re-opening Visual Studio and rebuilding the project?  Do you get this error just in the intellisense for Visual Studio, or also when building the project?

Answer (score 0):

The codes seems to be correct. You could check the page's **designer.cs** file to make sure that it has MyTB defined eg

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox MyTB;
```